Change the default name of EF Core generated join columns
When this code runs (FYI, the generic <TDbEntity> is a VgnItmDbEntity):
var entity = await context.Set<TDbEntity>().Include(e => e.VgnItmImages)
    .ThenInclude(vi => vi.Image)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(v => v.Id == id);

I get the error:

Exception has occurred: CLR/Npgsql.PostgresException Exception thrown:
'Npgsql.PostgresException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: '42703:
column v0.VgnItmDbEntityId does not exist
POSITION: 1163'    at
Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.d__233.MoveNext()
at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder1.StateMachineBox1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16
token)    at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.d__52.MoveNext()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.d__52.MoveNext()    at
Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.d__119.MoveNext()    at
Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.d__119.MoveNext()    at
Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.d__112.MoveNext()    at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.d__18.MoveNext()
at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.d__18.MoveNext()
at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.<InitializeReaderAsync>d__21.MoveNext() at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__72.MoveNext()
at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__20.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.d__151.MoveNext() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.<SingleOrDefaultAsync>d__151.MoveNext()
at Vepo.Data.VgnItmsRepository`5.d__9.MoveNext() in
/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_back_end/Vepo.Data/Repositories/VgnItms/VgnItmsRepository.cs:line
144

These are my entities and their configuration in OnModelCreating:
public class VgnItmDbEntity : CreatedBySomeoneDbEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(900)]
    public string WebPage { get; set; }

    public string Instagram { get; set; }
    public string Facebook { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int IsNotVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;

    [Required]
    public int IsVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;

    [Required]
    public int RatingsCount { get; set; } = 0;

    public double? Rating { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<int> Tags { get; set; }

    public List<int> SecondaryTags { get; set; }

    public int? PricePoint { get; set; }

    public ICollection<VgnItmImageDbEntity> VgnItmImages { get; set; }

    public string Discriminator { get; set; }
}

public class VgnItmImageDbEntity : CreatedBySomeoneDbEntity
{
    [ForeignKey(nameof(VgnItm))]
    public int VgnItmId { get; set; }
    public VgnItmDbEntity VgnItm { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Image))]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public ImageDbEntity Image { get; set; }
}

public class ImageDbEntity : CreatedBySomeoneDbEntity
{
    [Required]
    public Uri Url { get; set; }
    public List<int> Tags { get; set; }

    public ICollection<VgnItmImageDbEntity> VgnItmImages { get; set; } = new List<VgnItmImageDbEntity>();
}

public abstract class CreatedBySomeoneDbEntity : DbEntity<int>
{
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public UserDbEntity CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedById { get; set; }
    public UserDbEntity UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public abstract class DbEntity<TId>
{
    [Key]
    public TId Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    { 

        var uriConverter = new ValueConverter<Uri, string>(
            v => v == null ? null : v.ToString(),
            v => v == null ? null : new Uri(v)
            );

        modelBuilder.Entity<ImageDbEntity>(image =>
        {
            image.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
            image.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");

            image.Property(i => i.Url)
                .HasConversion(uriConverter);
        });

        // Vegan Item Images

        modelBuilder.Entity<VgnItmImageDbEntity>(viImage => 
        { 
            viImage.HasKey(e => new { e.VgnItmId, e.ImageId }); 

            viImage.HasOne(e => e.VgnItm) 
                .WithMany(v => v.VgnItmImages) 
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.VgnItmId); 

            viImage.HasOne(e => e.Image) 
                .WithMany(i => i.VgnItmImages) 
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ImageId); 

            viImage.HasIndex(g => new { g.VgnItmId, g.ImageId }).IsUnique(); 
            viImage.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); 
            viImage.Property(u => u.CreatedDate) 
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
            viImage.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate) 
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
            viImage.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy) 
                .WithMany() 
                .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById); 
            viImage.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy) 
                .WithMany() 
                .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById); 
        }); 

        modelBuilder.Entity<VgnItmDbEntity>(vgnItm =>
        {
            vgnItm.HasIndex("CompanyName", "Name", "Discriminator").IsUnique();
            vgnItm.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            vgnItm.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator")
                .HasValue<RecipeItmDbEntity>("RecipeItm")
                .HasValue<EventItmDbEntity>("EventItm")
                .HasValue<GroceryItmDbEntity>("GroceryItm")
                .HasValue<MenuItmDbEntity>("MenuItm")
                .HasValue<RestaurantItmDbEntity>("RestaurantItm")
                .HasValue<GroceryStoreItmDbEntity>("GroceryStoreItm")
                .HasValue<FashionItmDbEntity>("FashionItm");
            vgnItm.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
            vgnItm.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
            vgnItm.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            vgnItm.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
            vgnItm.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
            vgnItm.HasMany(e => e.VgnItmImages)
                .WithOne()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeItmDbEntity>(recipeItm =>
        {
            recipeItm.Property(e => e.Ingredients).HasColumnType("jsonb");
            recipeItm.Property(e => e.Method).HasMaxLength(100);
            recipeItm.Property(e => e.Tips).HasMaxLength(20);
            recipeItm.Property(e => e.Ingredients).HasMaxLength(100);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SingleLocationVgnItmDbEntity>(singleLocationVgnItm =>
        {
            singleLocationVgnItm.HasIndex("CompanyName", "Name", "Discriminator", "LocationId").IsUnique();
            singleLocationVgnItm
            .HasOne(s => s.Location) // Each SingleLocationVgnItm has one Location.
            .WithMany() // A Location can be associated with many SingleLocationVgnItm.
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.LocationId); // Foreign key in SingleLocationVgnItm pointing to Location.
        });

The column name is actaully VgnItmId, not VgnItmDbEntityId. I do not want any of my automatically generated EF Core columns to have DbEntity in the name. I had to do a manual migration to remove the VgnItmDbEntityId column, but EF Core still thinks it exists when doing runtime queries in the code.
How do I let EF Core know that the name of the column is not VgnItmDbEntityId, but rather VgnItmId?
I'm using EF Core 8.0.4. I am looking into if it is a bug.
This guy had a similar issue but i am already using his solution of HasForeignKey in onModelCreating.

It would be great if you could provide a [mre].

In the VgnItmDbEntity try changing:
vgnItm.HasMany(e => e.VgnItmImages)
    .WithOne() // potential problem
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

To:
vgnItm.HasMany(e => e.VgnItmImages)
    .WithOne(entity => entity.VgnItm)
    .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.VgnItmId) // potentially not needed
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

Your code had a lot of redundancy TBH, first of all it seems that a lot of the relations should be picked up by the EF conventions. Also you have the same relationship defined on both sides (defining on one side should be enough) and then via attributes also (and as written previously - EF should pick up automatically SomePropNameId and SomePropName relationship). If you do not want to rely on conventions and be explicit as much as possible - ideally stick to one way of describing the model (fluent API or attributes) and describe the relationship only "from one side" (i.e. in this case apply the suggested change and remove viImage.HasOne(e => e.VgnItm)...).

I had to do a manual migration to remove the VgnItmDbEntityId column, but EF Core still thinks it exists when doing runtime queries in the code.

You should not do this. If EF generates some structure - changing names in it via custom migrations without changing the model accordingly will not affect how EF perceives the database.

Amazing, it works, thank you! Will also do a refactor with your suggestions.
